# Autocomplete with TAB Read-host

Tags: powershell, read-host

I'm searching for something to autocomplete a user input in a `Read-Host` in Powershell. In my case, there is a list of 5 esxi hosts the user should be able to TAB through. Is there any way to do this inside of a Powershell script?

cheers,
Jonas

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.